# SQL filtering out if manytomany_id = x

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

swimset_styletag

```
id          swimset_id  styletag_id
----------  ----------  -----------
1           1           1          
2           2           2          
3           3           1          
4           3           2
```

swimset

```
id          set_description        
----------  -----------------------
1           4 x 100 Free Interval A
2           4 x 100 Back Interval A
3           6 x 100 free/back on in
```

styletag

```
id          tag_name  
----------  ----------
1           Free      
2           back
```

I'm trying to query swimsets that dont have styletag 2. so that they only set that returns should be swimset_id 1. However, when I try to use:

```
SELECT swimset_id, set_description, styletag_id
FROM swimset, swimset_styletag, styletag
WHERE
swimset.id = swimset_styletag.swimset_id AND swimset_styletag.styletag_id = styletag.id AND
swimset.styletag_id !=2;
```

I get swimset_id 1 AND 3 rather than just swimset_id 1. I imagine this is because in swimset_styletag, swimset_id 3 has two entries, one which hits styletag_id 1 and one which hits styletag_id 2. Is there a way to treat both swimset_id entries in swimset_styletag as one entry?

If this is something that should be addressed by a different database design, I'm also open to any suggestions as I'm still developing the exact design. When I was prototyping some python scripts without a database, I originally used mock data as True/False values paired with keys for each style tag. If I were to just add these styletag as True/False entries to the swimset table, this would allow a flat database, but seems uglier? Is something like that bad practice versus having many to many styletags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are after :

```
SELECT swimset.id, swimset.set_description, swimset_styletag.styletag_id
FROM swimset_styletag INNER JOIN
    swimset on swimset_styletag.swimset_id=swimset.id INNER JOIN 
    styletag on swimset_styletag.styletag_id=styletag.id
WHERE
swimset_id NOT IN (select swimset_id from swimset_styletag WHERE styletag_id=2)
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e4f0/20)

For removing multiple `styletag_id`s:

```
SELECT swimset.id, swimset.set_description, swimset_styletag.styletag_id
FROM swimset_styletag INNER JOIN
    swimset on swimset_styletag.swimset_id=swimset.id INNER JOIN 
    styletag on swimset_styletag.styletag_id=styletag.id
WHERE
swimset_id NOT IN (select swimset_id from swimset_styletag WHERE styletag_id IN (2,3,4,5,6))
```

Comment: I was about to accept, but it seems that its still returning both swimset 1 and swimset 3. I'd like for the sql to filter out swimset3 due to its having styletag 2 on one of its entries for swimset_styletag

Comment: Thanks. That does work. However, say I end up with 20 style tags, and each set has at least 10. If I want to exclude any swimset that has style tag 1, I'll need to write 9 more AND swimset_id NOT IN (...) statements? If the answer is yes, then maybe a flatter database design would be better?

Comment: BTW, we don't need the condition `swimset.styletag_id !=2;`. FYI, you can change `WHERE styletag_id=2` to `WHERE styletag_id IN (2,3,4,5,6)`.